# SQL: Using UNION

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union

Here is the question and database info.

Use the UNION command to prepare a full statement for customer 'C001' - it should be laid out as follows. (Note that the values shown below are not correct.) You may be able to use '' or NULL for blank values - if necessary use 0.
[image]

Here is a link to the webpage with the database info. http://sqlzoo.net/5_0.htm or see the image below.
[image]

Here is what I have tried:

```
    SELECT sdate AS LineDate, "delivery" AS LEGEND, price*quantity AS Total,"" AS Amount
    FROM shipped
    JOIN product ON (shipped.product=product.id)
    WHERE badguy='C001'
    UNION
    SELECT rdate,notes, "",receipt.amount
    FROM receipt
    WHERE badguy='C001'
```

Here is what I get back:

Wrong Answer. The correct answer has 5 row(s).

[image]

The amounts don't seem right in the amount column and I can't figure out how to order the data by the date since it is using two different date columns (sdate and rdate which are UNIONED).

Comment: Worded like homework... is it? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: It's from an online SQL tutorial -- see http://sqlzoo.net/5.htm -- so I doubt it's homework. Instead, it's a copyright violation. :-P

Comment: You'd probably get more help if you posted the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the data in the example is being aggregated by date and charge type using `group by`, that's why you are getting too many rows. 
Also, you can sort by the alias of the column (`LineDate`) and the `order by` clause will apply to all the rows in the `union`.

```
  SELECT sdate AS LineDate, "delivery" AS LEGEND, SUM(price*quantity) AS Total,"" AS Amount
    FROM shipped
    JOIN product ON (shipped.product=product.id)
    WHERE badguy='C001'
    GROUP BY sdate
    UNION
    SELECT rdate, notes, "",receipt.amount
    FROM receipt
    WHERE badguy='C001'
  ORDER BY LineDate
```

Comment: You actually don't even need the order-by clause; I tried this a few minutes ago, and it just needed the group-by clauses. The results weren't in date order, but it didn't care. (And I suspect that you're supposed to use a group-by in the second branch of the union as well, though there are no rows that would distinguish its presence from its absence, so I can't say for sure.)

Comment: You don't need the group by on the second `select` because you want to get all receipts.

Comment: How do you know? It seems to me that if you want to group all deliveries by date, then you'd also want to group all receipts by type and date.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually easiest to develop each part of the union separately. Pay attention to the use of "null" to separate the monetary columns.  The first select gets to name the columns.

```
select s.sdate as tr_date, 'Delivery' as type, sum((s.quantity * p.price)) as extended_price, null as amount
  from shipped s
  inner join product p on p.id = s.product
  where badguy = 'C001'
  group by s.sdate
union all
select rdate, notes, null, sum(amount)
  from receipt
  where badguy = 'C001'
  group by rdate, notes
order by tr_date
```